# How to set a minimum width in px and a maximum width based on the variable width of the browser window?

Tags: css

In this example:

http://jsbin.com/anoyik/edit#preview

http://jsbin.com/anoyik/edit#source

How can I set the red box's width to at least 200px and have it continue to expand in width as the browser window's width is extended horizontally?

Comment: `min-width:` might help you here. You need to remove `width: 200px`, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you: http://jsbin.com/exunik/2

The thing that keeps the black red box from expanding is that you had it set to inline-block. I added a min-width to the red box and set it to display: block. Then I floated the red box to the left to cause the black one to move into place on its right.

Answer (score 0):

## Expand both boxes

http://jsbin.com/anoyik/5/edit#preview

## Expand only red box

http://jsbin.com/anoyik/7/edit#preview